# BERTopic - TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, bert-language-model

I am trying to run the line `topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)` in a Jupyter notebook, but I keep getting an error that says "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer." I consulted someone who was able to resolve this issue by creating a new Anaconda environment that uses  NumPy 1.24.3 and Python 3.11.4. However, when I try to mimic him, I still get the error. Also, while it takes my laptop 20 minutes to run the fitting process, it only takes 3 minutes for my co-worker. I'm running the code on a MacBook with an Apple M1 chip, but I don't know if that fact is something of concern.

### Here are my error:

---

```py
          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py:3218, in BERTopic._cluster_embeddings(self, umap_embeddings, documents, partial_fit, y)
   3217 try:
-> 3218     self.hdbscan_model.fit(umap_embeddings, y=y)
   3219 except TypeError:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:1205, in HDBSCAN.fit(self, X, y)
   1196 kwargs.update(self._metric_kwargs)
   1198 (
   1199     self.labels_,
   1200     self.probabilities_,
   1201     self.cluster_persistence_,
   1202     self._condensed_tree,
   1203     self._single_linkage_tree,
   1204     self._min_spanning_tree,
-> 1205 ) = hdbscan(clean_data, **kwargs)
   1207 if self.metric != "precomputed" and not self._all_finite:
   1208     # remap indices to align with original data in the case of non-finite entries.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:884, in hdbscan(X, min_cluster_size, min_samples, alpha, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size, metric, p, leaf_size, algorithm, memory, approx_min_span_tree, gen_min_span_tree, core_dist_n_jobs, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, **kwargs)
   868             (single_linkage_tree, result_min_span_tree) = memory.cache(
   869                 _hdbscan_boruvka_balltree
   870             )(
   (...)
   880                 **kwargs
   881             )
   883 return (
--> 884     _tree_to_labels(
   885         X,
   886         single_linkage_tree,
   887         min_cluster_size,
   888         cluster_selection_method,
   889         allow_single_cluster,
   890         match_reference_implementation,
   891         cluster_selection_epsilon,
   892         max_cluster_size,
   893     )
   894     + (result_min_span_tree,)
   895 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:80, in _tree_to_labels(X, single_linkage_tree, min_cluster_size, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size)
   79 stability_dict = compute_stability(condensed_tree)
---> 80 labels, probabilities, stabilities = get_clusters(
   81     condensed_tree,
   82     stability_dict,
   83     cluster_selection_method,
   84     allow_single_cluster,
   85     match_reference_implementation,
   86     cluster_selection_epsilon,
   87     max_cluster_size,
   88 )
   90 return (labels, probabilities, stabilities, condensed_tree, single_linkage_tree)

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:659, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:733, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 # Run BERTopic model
----> 2 topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(abstract_corpus)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py:389, in BERTopic.fit_transform(self, documents, embeddings, images, y)
   386 umap_embeddings = self._reduce_dimensionality(embeddings, y)
   388 # Cluster reduced embeddings
--> 389 documents, probabilities = self._cluster_embeddings(umap_embeddings, documents, y=y)
   391 # Sort and Map Topic IDs by their frequency
   392 if not self.nr_topics:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py:3220, in BERTopic._cluster_embeddings(self, umap_embeddings, documents, partial_fit, y)
   3218     self.hdbscan_model.fit(umap_embeddings, y=y)
   3219 except TypeError:
-> 3220     self.hdbscan_model.fit(umap_embeddings)
   3222 try:
   3223     labels = self.hdbscan_model.labels_

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:1205, in HDBSCAN.fit(self, X, y)
   1195 kwargs.pop("prediction_data", None)
   1196 kwargs.update(self._metric_kwargs)
   1198 (
   1199     self.labels_,
   1200     self.probabilities_,
   1201     self.cluster_persistence_,
   1202     self._condensed_tree,
   1203     self._single_linkage_tree,
   1204     self._min_spanning_tree,
-> 1205 ) = hdbscan(clean_data, **kwargs)
   1207 if self.metric != "precomputed" and not self._all_finite:
   1208     # remap indices to align with original data in the case of non-finite entries.
   1209     self._condensed_tree = remap_condensed_tree(
   1210         self._condensed_tree, internal_to_raw, outliers
   1211     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:884, in hdbscan(X, min_cluster_size, min_samples, alpha, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size, metric, p, leaf_size, algorithm, memory, approx_min_span_tree, gen_min_span_tree, core_dist_n_jobs, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, **kwargs)
   867         else:
   868             (single_linkage_tree, result_min_span_tree) = memory.cache(
   869                 _hdbscan_boruvka_balltree
   870             )(
   (...)
   880                 **kwargs
   881             )
   883 return (
--> 884     _tree_to_labels(
   885         X,
   886         single_linkage_tree,
   887         min_cluster_size,
   888         cluster_selection_method,
   889         allow_single_cluster,
   890         match_reference_implementation,
   891         cluster_selection_epsilon,
   892         max_cluster_size,
   893     )
   894     + (result_min_span_tree,)
   895 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/vis_lab/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:80, in _tree_to_labels(X, single_linkage_tree, min_cluster_size, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size)
   78 condensed_tree = condense_tree(single_linkage_tree, min_cluster_size)
   79 stability_dict = compute_stability(condensed_tree)
---> 80 labels, probabilities, stabilities = get_clusters(
   81     condensed_tree,
   82     stability_dict,
   83     cluster_selection_method,
   84     allow_single_cluster,
   85     match_reference_implementation,
   86     cluster_selection_epsilon,
   87     max_cluster_size,
   88 )
   90 return (labels, probabilities, stabilities, condensed_tree, single_linkage_tree)

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:659, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:733, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: how does your `docs` look?

Comment: @Jeril Just added them to my post

Comment: can you upgrade the hdbscan to the latest version `v0.8.33`, run the following `python -m pip install -U hdbscan==0.8.33`

Comment: @Jeril I unfortunately still get the error

Comment: can you share you sklearn version?